# fetching data from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to using firebase, I am trying to fetch data from firebase. I have childIdArray, driverIdArray which I fetch from local database. I call method `getLocationFromFirebase` using the driverId and `dateFormatForDriverLocation(20170505)` I use for loop here because I have tableView where I show Estimate time arrival(eta) after calculating the etaArray. I have obseveEventType so that I can listen changes in location of Driver. Problem is I don't get the Index [i] of  of Driver whose location is changed.  [image]

```
var etaArray : [String] = []
var childIDArray : [String] = []
var childDriverArray : [Int] = []
var latitudeArray : [Double] = []
var longitudeArray : [Double] = []
var dateFormatForDriverLocation : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getCurrentLocationFromFirebase()

    let date = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
    dateFormatForDriverLocation = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

   }


func getCurrentLocationFromFirebase()
{
    let myGroup = dispatch_group_create()


    for i in 0 ..< self.childDriverArray.count {
        dispatch_group_enter(myGroup)
        var latitudeDriver = ""
        var longitudeDriver = ""
        let rootReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let DriverId = String(self.childDriverArray[i])
        let pickLat = String(latitudeArray[i])
        let pickLong = String(longitudeArray[i])



        let driverPath = rootReference.child("gogoapp_driver/\(DriverId)")

        driverPath.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in


            if snapshot.hasChild(self.dateFormatForDriverLocation!)
            {

                if let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("\(self.dateFormatForDriverLocation!)") as? FIRDataSnapshot
                {

                    let currentDateData : FIRDataSnapshot = childSnapshot
                    print(i)
                    //for getting the last value of location
                    let child = currentDateData.children.reverse()[0]
                    if let latitude = child.value!!["latitude"] as? String
                    {
                        latitudeDriver = latitude
                    }
                    if let longitude = child.value!!["longitude"] as? String
                    {
                        longitudeDriver = longitude
                    }


                    self.GoogleDistanceMatrixApi(latitudeDriver, driverLong: longitudeDriver, pickUpLat: pickLat, pickUpLong: pickLong, completion: {(success) -> Void in

                        if success.isEmpty
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            self.etaArray[i] = success


                        }
                    })

                }
            }

        })

        dispatch_group_leave(myGroup)

    }

}


 func GoogleDistanceMatrixApi(driverLat : String, driverLong : String, pickUpLat : String, pickUpLong : String, completion:((sucess: String) -> Void)) {
     var Text = "as"
     completion(sucess: TEXT!) 
 }
```

Comment: You seem to be passing in the `167` value already in `"gogoapp_driver/\(DriverId)"`. What value are you looking to get?

Comment: Is the intention here to add an .value observer to every driver child node?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen there are many DriverIds in the childDriverArray[167,172,187,199]. i store it in variable DriverId and give the path and add observer. Everytime there's change in location of any particular driver id method is called.. but i don't get whose location is changed, is it 167 or 172 or 187 or 199

Comment: @Jay i want to listen the changes in every driver that is stored in childDriverArray

Comment: Just add an observer to the gogoapp_driver node. It will notify the app if there's a change to any drivers in the node. When you get the event, simply compare it to your array of drivers and if it's not one of them, ignore it. It would actually be 'cooler' to determine what the correlation is between the drivers in the array, and instead of adding an observer to the gogoapp_driver node, add a query to send events for certain drivers that match the criteria. i.e. query for drivers who have SUV's.